# jQuery Rotate Function Img Selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html, selector

**I'm trying to** use jQuery to rotate an image 90 degrees upon click on my div.
Why doesn't it work?

Here's my HTML ...

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <img id="whatever">
    </div>
</div>
```

.. and here's my jQuery ;

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery(".class1").click(function()
               {
            jQuery(this).find('img').rotate({animateTo:-90})
               });
             });
```

If it helps,
http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

NOTE: **I need the code to FIND the first image...not just get the image by id, then rotate it.**

Comment: Are you sure the rotate plugin is being loaded? What error does Chrome console or Firebug console show you?

Comment: I'm not sure as to how to check the Chrome console.

Just checked it. Got this error:
'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'rotate' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @Abdullah Jibaly post and look at comment. I think you miss something like

```
<script src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
```

And here is an example to rotate at first image http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/BeUBF/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine as is, I'd guess that the plugin is not being loaded or something else outside the given context went wrong.

To get the first img you can use:

```
jQuery(this).find('img').first().rotate({animateTo:-90})
```

Comment: Open Chrome console or Firebug console, you should see an error.

Comment: In Chrome, use Cmd + Option + i (mac).

Comment: I think Windows is Ctr + Alt + i or Ctrl + Shift + i.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'rotate'

Comment: Yep, that's most likely that the plugin failed to load.

Comment: Go to the Network tab (next to Chrome console) and see why jquery.rotate.js failed to load.

Answer (score 1):

// according to use it

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" >
    </div>
</div>
        <button id='test'>click</button>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var setvalue=90;
    jQuery("#test").click(function() {
        jQuery('.class1').find('img').rotate({
            animateTo: setvalue
        });
                setvalue=setvalue+90;        
    });
});
</script>
```

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 0):

fisrt letter of `class` name should not be a number, change them to `class1` and `class2` instead and add quotation marks for `animateTo` value:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <img id="whatever">
    </div>
</div>

  $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".class1").click(function(){
            $(this).find('img').rotate({animateTo: "-90"})
       });
  });
```

Comment: I wrote '1' and '2' just as examples. In my script, they're words. I fixed it here though.

Comment: Not sure how to check. I'm using chrome.

Comment: so right click in the viewport and select `Inspect Element` and find the Console section and check it out.

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'rotate'

Comment: so it means that you have not loaded the plugin, check the `script` tag, be sure that the path to the  plugin is correct and jquery core library has been loaded before the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">
            <img id="whatever">
        </div>
    </div>


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".class1").click(function()
    {
       $("#whatever").rotate(90);
    });
});
```